# Add a UIPageViewController programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, collections, uipageviewcontroller

I am trying to add a `UIPageViewController` programmatically to a custom `UICollectionViewCell`. At expected result I want to be able to swipe between different controllers inside the `UICollectionViewCell`. This is the code I wrote:

```
import UIKit

class SlidingCellCell : UICollectionViewCell, UIPageViewControllerDataSource, UIPageViewControllerDelegate{


    var pages = [UIViewController]()
    let pageControl = UIPageControl()
    let pageViewController = UIPageViewController()

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        pageViewController.dataSource = self
        pageViewController.delegate = self
        let initialPage = 0
        let page1 = myViewController1()
        let page2 = myViewController1()
        let page3 = myViewController1()
        self.pages.append(page1)
        self.pages.append(page2)
        self.pages.append(page3)
        pageViewController.setViewControllers([pages[initialPage]], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
        pageViewController.view.frame = self.frame
    }
```

I am stuck on adding `pageViewController` to the `cell`. If I write `self.addSubview(pageViewController)` I get an error telling me that the function is expecting a `UIView`.

I also have another error telling me that the class dose not conform the `protocol UIPageViewControllerDataSource`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1. For Error: function is expecting a `UIView`.**

```
override func awakeFromNib()
{
    super.awakeFromNib()
    //Your code..

    self.contentView.addSubview(pageViewController.view)
}
```

**2. For Error: class dose not conform the protocol `UIPageViewControllerDataSource`.**

Implement the below methods:

```
func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?
{
    //TODO:
}

func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?
{
    //TODO:
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First you have to add the viewcontroller's view to the cell and take care about the childviewcontroller's lifecycle in the meantime eg.:

```
pageViewController.willMove(toParentViewController: <cell's parent viewcontroller coming here>)
addSubview(pageViewController.view)
pageViewController.view.frame = bounds // Set the viewcontroller's view's size, or do it with constraints
pageViewController.didMove(toParentViewController: <same as above>)
```

After this you have to implement these two methods in the cell (I don't recommend to create the viewcontrollers there, but that is another topic)

```
func pageViewController(UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?

func pageViewController(UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?
```